# How to use Volume Shadows Copy and Robocopy on Win7?

Tags: powershell, robocopy, volume-shadow-copy

I’d like to backup my system with Robocopy and Powershell, but Robocopy is not able to copy open files. Volume Shadows Copy seems a solution but I can’t find any clear and simple explanation on how to use it. Is there any documentation out there that is clear and simple?

I’m running on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise. Thanks for your help. Franck

Comment: Google for Adi Oltean. His blog had good info on getting VSS snapshots mounted for other scripts to use. You might also find the open source HoboCopy tool handy.

Comment: [Adi Oltean's Weblog - Flashbacks on technology, programming, and other interesting things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/)

Comment: @afrazier I did not see your comment till after I posted my answer, if you want to post your comment as a answer I will delete my answer and vote up yours for mentioning it first (by over a year :) )

Answer (score 2):

Check out the WMI [Win32_ShadowCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389391(v=vs.85).aspx) class. It has a Create method:

```
(Get-WmiObject -list win32_shadowcopy).Create("C:\","ClientAccessible")
```

I like [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) as a fully built VSS backup solution. It's free.

Answer (score 2):

There is a open source project called [HoboCopy](https://github.com/candera/hobocopy) which is a bit of a clone of RoboCopy but it will natively use the Volume Shadow Copy Service when trying to create it's backups.

Comment: FYI: HoboCopy has had no update since 2010. Its creator declares ShadoSpawn as a replacement but that has also seen no update since 2010.